# How to concatenate first row with each remaining rows and second row with below each remaining rows for 7 cycles in Python?

Tags: python, loops, nested-loops

I've been messing around with a few different solutions for how to concatenate

1. Iterate 1st row with each row until last(n).
2. After step1, Iterate 2nd row with each of remaining rows. So on 3rd row and till n(last row)-1 which is called as first cycle.
3. Similarly for second cycle which is combination of first two rows with 3rd row.

Below is **sample output** which I want to be loaded in **Excel** or **CSV** when I give input ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'].

```
1_cycle     2_cycle     3_cycle     4_cycle       5_cycle         6_cycle
 A&B          A,B&C     A,B,C&D    A,B,C,D&E     A,B,C,D,E&F    A,B,C,D,E,F&G
 A&C          A,B&D     A,B,C&E    A,B,C,D&F     A,B,C,D,E&G    
 A&D          A,B&E     A,B,C&F    A,B,C,D&G     B,C,D,E,F&G    
 A&E          A,B&F     A,B,C&G    B,C,D,E&F        
 A&F          A,B&G     A,B,C&E    B,C,D,E&G        
 A&G          A,C&D     A,B,C&F    C,D,E,F&G        
 B&C          A,C&E     A,B,C&G         
 B&D          A,C&F     A,B,C&F         
 B&E          A,C&G     A,B,C&G         
 B&F          A,D&E     B,C,D&E         
 B&G          A,D&F     B,C,D&F         
 C&D          A,D&G     B,C,D&G         
 C&E          A,E&F     C,D,E&F         
 C&F          A,E&G     C,D,E&G         
 C&G          A,F&G     D,E,F&G         
 D&E          B,C&D             
 D&F          B,C&E             
 D&G          B,C&F             
 E&F          B,C&G             
 E&G          C,D&E             
 F&G          C,D&F             
              C,D&G             
              D,E&F             
              D,E&G             
              E,F&G
```

So far, I am able to crack the first cycle. It's just when it comes to second cycle and third cycle I'm having trouble.

At the moment, I have this code below that is working for first cycle.

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import os
import csv

links=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']
len = len(links)

A=0
B=1
csvfile = open('permutation_loop.csv', 'a',encoding='utf-8')
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

for i in links:
    first = i
    A+=1
    #print(first)
    for j in links[A:]:
        second = j
        B+=1
        first_cycle = first+second
        #print(second)
        #csvwriter.writerow([first_cycle.strip()])
        for k in links[B:]:
            third = k
            #print(third)
            second_cycle = first+second+third
            print(second_cycle)
            csvwriter.writerow([first_cycle,second_cycle])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv


def one_cycle(original_inputs, previous_step):
    for i, x in previous_step:
        for j in range(i + 1, len(original_inputs)):
            yield (j, x + [original_inputs[j]])


def many_cycles(original_inputs, num_cycles):
    strings = [(i, [letter]) for i,letter in enumerate(original_inputs)]
    for i in range(num_cycles):
        strings = list(one_cycle(original_inputs, strings))
        yield (letter for index, letter in strings)


def insert_comma_ampersand(inp):
    # transforms ['A','B','C','D'] to 'A,B,C&D'
    comma_part = ','.join(inp[:-1])
    return f'{comma_part}&{inp[-1]}'


def make_permutations_csv(letters, num_cycles):
    csv_file = open('permutation_loop.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, lineterminator='\n')

    csv_writer.writerow([f'{i+1}_cycle' for i in range(num_cycles)])

    columns = list(many_cycles(letters, num_cycles))
    while not all(column is None for column in columns):
        row = []
        for i, column in enumerate(columns):
            if column is None:
                row.append('')
                continue

            try:
                row.append(insert_comma_ampersand(next(column)))
            except StopIteration:
                row.append('')
                columns[i] = None
        csv_writer.writerow(row)

    csv_file.close()


make_permutations_csv(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], 6)
```

Comment: Code is working as required. Thanks for the code.
There is a small change in output. As I want to add "," after each output and "&" before the last character. 
As I edited the sample output format.
And also I would like to save the output in excel in separate columns as like the sample output.

Comment: @bharath can you edit the question to give an idea of what you would like the CSV file to look like? Maybe one cycle per row? Also, should the input row be included in the CSV?

Comment: I have re-edited the question, As I want to load/save the output into Excel or CSV same as headers like Sample Output in question.

Comment: Thank you very much @Oli I really appreciate. Code is working with exact requirement.

Comment: I am facing small issue, When I am giving an input ['Blue','Black','White',3]. The output comings as B,l,u,e,B,l,a,c&K(1_cycle) which ',' & '&' is coming for each letter, As I require ',' & '&' should coming for each word like Blue&Black(1_cycle) , Blue,Black&White(2_Cyle).

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I didn't consider that inputs may be more than a single letter. Fixed!